# How To Test a Vaadin PWA App from a Mobile Device

Tags: vaadin, progressive-web-apps, mobile-safari

I'm trying to test my Vaadin PWA app from my iPhone. The app is built and running in production mode. All of the PWA config seems to be in place including SSL enabled. I can access the app from the computer that is running the Vaadin app server (SpringBooted - Tomcat), using the same URL. It does not appear to be a network problem but the app does not load into the Safari or Brave browser on the mobile device.  App server and mobile are both connected to the same wireless network. I can ping from the mobile device to the server.  Any ideas?

App should load into the browser when accessed.

I deployed the app as a war to stand-alone Tomcat. Issue remains.  I noticed that iOS devices can reach an application running on port 443 but not 8080 or 8443.  Is this some kind of port limit in iOS devices?

Comment: Have you checked the dev-console?

Comment: : Vaadin is running in production mode.
`: Tomcat started on port(s): 8443 (https) with context path ''
: Started Application in 5.028 seconds (JVM running for 5.579)
: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
: Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
: Completed initialization in 1 ms`

Comment: I tried to access the app from another computer, not device, and it too cannot connect. This tells me that its the Vaadin embedded Tomcat that is not letting non-localhost connections.  Any ideas how to configure that?

Comment: Regarding your answer being deleted - To me, it seems like your answer sounded a bit like a "I'm still having this problem, can someone help me?" and not an actual answer. But if you want to know why this happened, you can ask on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) or maybe there's someone able to help you in the [SOCVR chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers). - But that's no reason to attempt to answer it in an edit.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Chrome
2. add the server ip address in  "Insecure origins treated as secure" from the page: chrome://flags

Comment: Those settings don't exist in the mobile version of Chrome.

Comment: Hi, Taylor. Did you tried to write in the address bar of chrome on mobile "chrome://flags"?  I every day use those settings for test my PWA.